# ¿Cómo definir una funcion para que busque varios campos a la vez? Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Actualmente el buscador solo encuentra lo que esta en la columna de noticiero_turno, pero como se podría encontrar las demás columnas que son (noticiero_programa y noticiero_fecha)

**Función del controlador**

```
public function busqueda(Request $request)
{
  $ntc_turno = $request->input('noticiero_turno');
  if($ntc_turno){
    $noticia = Noticia::where('noticiero_turno','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")->paginate(2);
    return view('noticia.listar',array('noticia'=>$noticia));
  }else{
    $noticia = Noticia::paginate(3); 
    return view('noticia.listar',array('noticia'=>$noticia));

  }
}
```

**Vista del controlador**

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')

<div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">Buscar</div>
    <form action="/noticia/buscar" method="get" onsubmit="return showLoad()">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <label class="label-control">Buscar</label>
        <input type="text" name="noticiero_turno" class="form-control" placeholder="Please input stock name/description" required="required">
            <br>

    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
@if (isset($noticia))
<div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">Resultado de busqueda</div>
        <div class="panel-body">

    <div class='table-responsive'>
     <table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
         <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Turno</th>
          <th>Fecha</th>

          </tr>
          </thead>
         <tbody>
        @foreach($noticia as $buscar)
            <tr>
            <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_programa']}}</td>
            <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_turno']}}</td>
            <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_fecha']}}</td>

            @endforeach
            </tbody>

            </table>
<center>{{ $noticia->appends(Request::only('noticiero_turno'))->links() }}</center>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
        <a href="{{url('noticia/buscar')}}" class="btn btn-warning">Reset Search</a>
        </div>
</div>
@endif

@stop
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ruta**

```
 Route::get('noticia/buscar', 'NoticiaController@busqueda');
```

**MODELO**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Noticia extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['noticiero_programa','noticiero_turno','noticiero_fecha'];

    public function notas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\nota', 'noticia_id');
    }




}
```

Comment: desde tu buscador quieres que busque cualquiera de esos campos?, o simplemente no sabes como hacerlo desde el html hasta laravel

Comment: desde el buscador que busque cualquiera de esos campos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Laravel** y su `orm eloquent` son de sintaxis sencilla para sus consultas.

Para buscar en mas de una campo de la base de datos se debe concatenar (valga el termino) `where` tras `where`(esto para una sentencia `and` en sql) y colocar tantos sean necesarios para nuestra consulta, en caso de un `or` (este es tu caso) de sql se debe de iniciar por un `where` seguidos por los `orWhere` que sean necesarios.

**Solucion a tu problema:**

```
$noticia = Noticia::where('noticiero_turno','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
                    ->orWhere('noticiero_programa','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
                    ->orWhere('noticiero_fecha','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
                    ->paginate(2);
```

Claro que esta consulta te retornara resultados del cualquiera de los campos visto.